# Changing a value before calling another constructor

Tags: c#

I have been trying to create some "cascading" constructors. One calls the other with more information that before. The two I have so far look like this.

```
public scan() : this(Environment.Local) { }
public scan(Environment env) {
    //it then does some stuff constructor-y things
}
```

I would like to make another one that can call my second constructor by accepting a string that it will then convert into an `Environment`. Something to this effect:

```
public scan(string environment) : this(environment.toString()}
```

but it just doesn't seem to want to work how I am hoping. Is there a way to pass in this string then call my other environment accepting constructor?

Also the change i'm hoping to make is going to more substantial than just a `toString()` but I used that to illistrate the point.

Comment: What is this Environment class you're using? It's not the System.Environment static class.

Comment: @KoBE it is not, it is an enum I made within the same class as my scan()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way: Create a static method that handles converting from string to enum. In this static method, check for validity and return local if not.

```
public class scan
{
    public scan(Environment value) { }
    public scan() : this(Environment.Local) { }
    public scan(string s) : this(ParseEnum(s)) { }

    private static Environment ParseEnum(string s)
    {
        // default to local
        Environment value = Environment.Local;

        // try parsing the string
        Enum.TryParse<Environment>(s, out value);

        // if sucessful, the new value will be returned
        // if not, Environment.Local will be returned
        return value;
    }
    public enum Environment
    {
        Local,
        NotLocal,
        AnotherOne
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated the code to use TryParse(), which I feel is a little cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

`ToString` won't work because you end up calling the constructor recursively (plus calling `ToString` on a `string` doesn't make much sense).  It sounds like you want to `Parse` te string to an `Environment` value:

```
public scan(string environment) : 
      this((Environment)Enum.Parse(typeof(Environment),environment))
{
}
```

But you run the risk of an exception being thrown due to an invalid string value, which cannot be caught at compile time.

Comment: Nice answer. Good thing the compiler would catch the ambiguous constructor before it's even built . The invalid string value can be fixed with a static method as I point out below.

Answer (score 0):

No. You cant call constructor *inside* of other constructor or do something with parameter inside your constructor that is passed to other constructor *before* other ctor is called. Yes you can call other constructor and pass result of method execution like `ctor() : this(MyMethod())` but still it is not the same as calling other constructor *from inside of your ctor*.

Typically what is used is  :

```
public scan() { // general initialization logic }

public scan(Environment env) : this() 
{
    //some special logic here that uses parameter env
}
```

Or something like windows forms `InitializeComponent` method. Initialization method that contains initialization logic.

Comment: Yes you can. Calling other constructors is pretty much the same as calling other methods. Once a constructor has been called, it's basically a redirection to whichever method you want to use. Including other constructors.

Comment: @KoBE Could you please add screenshot where you call construrctor **INSIDE** of other constructor ... It is NOT the same as calling methods because constructor is only invoked once upon creation of object and NOT like method (that you can call anywhere and anytime in your code).

Comment: You can have multiple parameter overloads for constructors, thus you can call a constructor from another constructor. It's OOP 101.

Comment: @Bauss it is possible only to do inline in a ctor signature like `ctor() : this(string s)` but not *inside* the constructor (therefore doing some logic and only then calling other ctor). That's why it's *not* like it is with methods.

Comment: @Fabjan You are correct, you cannot call other constructors from *inside* the body of another constructor. I was unclear on my response.

Answer (score 0):

If `Environment` was a struct or a class, then you could override the casting operator and rewrite your contructor like this:

```
public scan(string environment) : this((Environment)environment)
```

It is not allowed to overload operators on Enum types, so you're out of luck here.